# Write To Standard Output When No Console Present

Tags: c#

Console.Write* works as expected when used with a console application, or a windowed application with a console attached.

However, if I make an application that does not have a console and run it from the command line, it does not output as expected. It appears to start the application asynchronously as the prompt reappears while the program is still running.

How can I output in such a way that text output will appear in an attached console or a command prompt that runs it? Or, how do I run the application differently where it waits correctly and captures the expected output?

Comment: If it isn't a console application, then launching it from a console window will have the same effect as launching any other Windows application from a console window. The same as launching it from the Run... dialog. If you want a console application, you need to change your project accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a Logger framework, rather than relying on Console. Logging frameworks provide a variety of ways to consume their logs, so you can decide which way works best for you without having to change your code.

For example, if you're using a logging framework that's set to output log messages to the console for the sake of a console app, you only have to change one configuration option to make it output to a file, which you can use a tool like Baretail to watch even if you don't have the console open. Or you can easily change the configuration to output to `System.Diagnostics.Debug` so that it appears in the Visual Studio Output window.

Comment: You don't even need anything complicated. You can just use the built-in Trace class, and hook into it with a TraceListener. Of course, there are some awfully nice logging frameworks... :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: The funny thing is that using a logging framework doesn't have to be complicated, and yet the future-proofing that you get from using it instead of Console, Debug, or Trace is so beneficial. As a rule of thumb, I'd recommend using a logging framework for anything more complicated than a LINQPad script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting debug output to appear in Visual Studio, use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` to output to the "Immediate" window in VS while the application is running.  Wrap is in "IF" precompiler directives so that it won't happen when you compile into a non-debug build.  Any lines inside the "IF" will be completely ignored by the compiler if the current build target does not have the "DEBUG" flag set (like the default "Release" build target).

```
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()
#endif
```

Comment: The [methods on System.Diagnostics.Debug](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Debug.cs) all have a `[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute on them, so the precompiler directive isn't necessary.

Comment: Would Console.Stderr.Writeline() not print into the immediate window?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you are correct. Wasn't thinking about that. The pre-compiler directive isn't necessary.